# Change style of error line (cap size and dash) in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I using plotly express to plot a scatter with error lines for the y-axis. Here's a MWE:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(
        y=np.array([13,21,19]),
        x=np.array([10,18,15]),
        error_y = np.array([1,2,3])
    )
fig.update_traces(textposition="bottom right", marker=dict(
        color='black')
)
fig.show()
```

I want to change the style of the error line. First, I want to delete the cap, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500280/removing-error-bar-caps-in-matplotlib). Second, I would like to make a dashed line instead of the solid line.

I looked through the Plotly [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter/#scatter-error_y), but I don't see a straightforward way to do this. By adjusting the marker you cannot change the line apparently.

Thanks for any help or idea.

Comment: To my recollection, there is no example of changing to a dashed line. This [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76545549/unilateral-error-bars-in-plotly-stacked-bar-chart) may be helpful for techniques to process the whiskers.

Comment: `width=0` should resolve the cap issue.

Comment: @AliMassoud that solved the cap issue, yes. Many thanks. For the record, I added  this line: fig.update_traces(error_y=dict(width=0))